# Dict Union in Data Factory Expression

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to combine some dictionaries within Data Factory's expressions, but so far have found it nearly impossible to do this in an elegant way, and my solutions so far are quite difficult to manage. So is the workaround below the only way of merging dictionaries in Data Factory? Or is there a simpler way of doing this that I am missing?

### Working Baseline

Let's start with a basic pipeline with two input parameters:

- `a` (Object) with default `{"a": 1}`
- `b` (Object) with default `{"b": 2}`

Add a "Set Variable" activity which creates a union of `a` and `b` and converts it to a string:

```
@string(union(
    pipeline().parameters.a,
    pipeline().parameters.b
))
```

This works and produces the expected out:

```
{
    "name": "output",
    "value": "{\"a\":1,\"b\":2}"
}
```

### Non-working Extension

Let's suppose I want to add some metadata to the output dict. I would have expected that I can do this:

```
@string(union(
    pipeline().parameters.a,
    pipeline().parameters.b,
    {'datetime': utcNow()}
))
```

but this does not work as it is apparently invalid syntax.

#### Workaround

I have found that it is possible to wrap a JSON string in the `json` function:

```
@string(union(
    pipeline().parameters.a,
    pipeline().parameters.b,
    json('{"c": 3}')
))
```

But this seems rather cumbersome. In particular, it does not seem to be possible to use `@{...}` on the internal strings and instead one must resort to clunky uses of `concat`:

```
@string(union(
    pipeline().parameters.a,
    pipeline().parameters.b,
    json(concat(
        '{"datetime": "',
        utcNow(),
        '"}'
    ))
))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To build an object, you are using union on the parameters. But since the datetime object is not available, we have to build it using `utcNow()` function.
- The method that you are using is not a workaround, it is the way to build the JSON object.
- String interpolation`@{...}` is helps us to use dynamic content within expression builder, but not inside function arguments.
- One way so that it is easily understandable is to split the activity. Create the datetime object in one set variable and then apply `union()` in another.
- To build the datetime object, use the following dynamic content:

```
{"datetime":"@{utcnow()}"}
```

[image]

- Now you can apply union in the following way:

```
@string(union(
    pipeline().parameters.a,
    pipeline().parameters.b,
    json(variables('demo'))
))
```

[image]